# Postgres: launching an sql after the docker image started

Tags: postgresql

i need to create a docker image based on "postgres", and to launch an sql statement, i suppose by using `pgsql`, *after* the image started.

The idea is that i should create a .sh script, like the following:

`pgsql -U username database -f statement.sql`

(since we're on localhost, pgsql should be allowed to connect to the db).

Is this the correct approach ? I am not able, anyway, to launch the script *after* the server started, i have connection failure because the image is not started.

What's the right way to **extend** an existing docker image without copying all the setup of the base image ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you please elaborate about where the script is being run from? Is it packaged inside the image? Or is it being run from the host machine? Also, to answer the second part of your question, the way to extend an image is to use the `FROM` directive - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I know that the `FROM` clause does exactly this. But, specifically, i want to create an image that _extends_ the standard `postgres` one, and that _after_ all the step of the basic docker image, executes an sql. How to do this is irrelevant, as long as i can achieve to make it then the container starts.

I have been told right now that the right way to do this would be by starting the container, logging in to make the necessary changes, and then making a **commit**. Is this the right way ?